# Bluetooth app not working on devices running on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I made a Bluetooth app. It works fine in `Nougat`, `Marshmallow`, `Jelly Bean`, `KitKat` but for reason, it crashes in Android `Lollipop` when `Discover` button (which discovers all the discoverable devices) is clicked.

Here is the method which gets triggered on clicking `Discover` button -

```
private void discoverDevices() {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }


    }
```

**CheckBTPermissions()-**

```
private void checkBTPermissions() {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version 
=< LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }
```

**Permissions in Manifest file-**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
```

**build.gradle-**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hpi5.bluetooth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**I have not tested this app on Lollipop myself as I don't have any device running on Android L.** I got to know about the crash from a friend of mine.

**EDIT: I managed to arrange the logs.**

```
07-07 19:29:00.219 30852-30852/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.hpi5.bluetooth, PID: 30852
                                                   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method checkSelfPermission(Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Lcom/example/hpi5/bluetooth/MainActivity; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.hpi5.bluetooth.MainActivity' appears in /data/app/com.example.hpi5.bluetooth-1/base.apk)
                                                       at com.example.hpi5.bluetooth.MainActivity.checkBTPermissions(MainActivity.java:243)
                                                       at com.example.hpi5.bluetooth.MainActivity.discoverDevices(MainActivity.java:230)
                                                       at com.example.hpi5.bluetooth.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                       at com.example.hpi5.bluetooth.MainActivity$7.onClick(MainActivity.java:189)
                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4923)
                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20341)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: The app might crash if user rejects the permission request. Add `requestPermissionsResult` callback function

Comment: Requesting Permissions at Run Time was introduced in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) but the app crashes only in Android 5.0 (Lollipop) where there is no chance of rejecting the permission request at the run time. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You could download the lollipop emulator in Android studio, and see if you also receive this error. You can now see the error in logcat, or you could add Crashlytics to your app, so you will get a stacktrace when the app crashes.

Comment: Android emulator does not have bluetooth capabilities

Comment: bluetooth is not gonna work on emulator
and could you please tell me what's your friend's phone ,and show exceptions and add requestPermissionsResult() see if it's permission denial . and .. show the exceptions with noFilter

Comment: When exactly does the app crash? In which activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I arranged the logs somehow and found even for devices running on Lollipop the following condition was evaluating to true

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //code here
}
```

and because of this, the app was crashing on clicking the **Discover** button.

So, I just changed the above condition to -

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

}
```

The app is working fine on Lollipop devices now.

**Why was it crashing on Lollipop devices earlier?**

So, my friend's device was running on Android version 5.1.1 and that is why the condition was evaluating to true. And since `checkSelfPermission` was introduced in API level 23 (Android M), the app could not find it and thus crashed.

Answer (score 4):

The exception says it all, the method checkSelfPermission is only available on API 23 onwards. If you want to check permission with API 21, use the Android support library and [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))

Edit: Also, location permissions for Bluetooth are only required from API 23 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime permission system was added in API 23, so you shouldn't check permissions under that API. And logcat tells you that it can't find a method that didn't existed in API 21.